# WEKA Instance.ClassAttribute() method

Tags: java, data-mining, weka

I WEKA, I came across the following code:

```
Instances train = DataSource.read(args[0]);
train.setClassIndex(train.numAttributes() - 1);
Instances test = DataSource.read(args[1]);
test.setClassIndex(test.numAttributes() - 1);
// train classifier
J48 cls = new J48();
cls.buildClassifier(train);
// output predictions
System.out.println("# - actual - predicted - distribution");
for (int i = 0; i < test.numInstances(); i++) {
    double pred = cls.classifyInstance(test.instance(i));
    double[] dist = cls.distributionForInstance(test.instance(i));
    System.out.print((i+1) + " - ");
    System.out.print(test.instance(i).toString(test.classIndex()) + " - ");
    System.out.print(test.classAttribute().value((int) pred) + " - ");
    System.out.println(Utils.arrayToString(dist));
}
```

The objective here is to run a pre-built classifier on a test set of data, and then to print the actual class, predicted class and the class membership value distribution.
I understand everything except one line:

```
System.out.print(test.classAttribute().value((int) pred) + " - ");
```

If "test" is a group of instances, how will the above statement be able to print the predicted class value for the current instance inside the for loop?

Thanks
Abhishek S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `test.classAttribute()` gives you all the classes that the test instances could be assigned to. The second part `.value((int) pred)` then selects the class out of this group which matches to `pred`, which is the predicted class for the current test instance.